# What's missing in my Processing Page? Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

What am I missing in my processing page? I used already cached in Filtered View. but I can't catch those checked checkboxes per line. I already checked CommitChanges = true and AutoCallback.CommitChanges = true, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the processing page is or isn't doing from what you expect to occur?

Comment: I think he is trying to get the Selected column to generate events. Reading/writing the Selected field in processing screen doesn't work when I tested it, workarounds are complicated to do. The only place where I can successfully read the Selected value without workarounds is in the process delegate. I believe there is a few special cases and exceptions related to Selected DAC field in a processing screen. Some people have voiced a different opinion, it would be nice to know if we can treat Selected as a normal field or avoid it because it has different behaviors.

Comment: I am just trying to selecting multiple what I want to post to another screen.

Comment: I am using process delegate, with my 
PXAction
[PXProcessButton(CommitChanges =true)]

I also done this

Comment: I used (this.View/Filter.Cache.Cached) in foreach, but I can't iterate those data that I've selected. It just shows nothing

Comment: Inside the process delegate handler you can iterate the list of DAC or single DAC passed as a parameter. In that context the Selected value will be good. In other context or when accessing through a different mechanism the values are not reliable. If someone can chime in and deny this observation that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate some example? I'm really lost